# Are divisions of returns linear?

Tags: rate-of-return

If I have an annualized 5% return on $2,000, which is $100, can I always say that each 1% is $20?

If that is the case, then this linear division of an annualized returns can be applied to more complex scenarios. For example, you buy an option requiring $500 and hold it for 60 days, netting $30. That's 6% on the holding period and 36% (12/2 x .06) annualized. Each annualized 6% in that case is $5 right?

Comment: Rates of return are always compounded.

Comment: Simple math says that $20 is 1% of $2,000.  You learned that in grade school.  As for your second paragraph: after that sixty days, would you buy another $500 option, netting $30?  And sixty days later, buy another $500 option, netting $30?

Comment: This looks like what’s called an X-Y problem: you really want to know X, but you’re asking about Y. In this case, Y is a simple division: 100/5=20. What is your underlying question (the X)? Are you trying to work out, for example, the expected gain from a short-duration transaction, given an expected annualised yield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common calculations include gross return, net return, percent return, annualized return and if you want, compound return.

How is a 6% return on an option that cost $500 a more complex scenario than earning $100 on $2,000?  Yield is yield.

If you want to do " linear division of an annualized returns", go for it.  If you do, what edge does that give you in your investing/trading?